# Ruby on Rails Amending Index Page localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm extremely new to Ruby and am having a few basic issues with the way the rails framework works. We have Models / Controllers / Views that we route to create extra "pages" in each application. But how do i actually change the index page (localhost:3000 / index in the directory) to ensure that the root of my program is at the top of the tree?

I was under the impression that it may be in the layout view (application.html.erb) but changes to that class have made no difference. There also aren't any other routes that i can see clearly that affect where the page redirects to.

Comment: you need to provide root option in your router and then manage that page, see http://docs.railsbridge.org/intro-to-rails/setting_the_default_page

Comment: So i would essentially uncomment the root route and set it to my desired controller / view?

Comment: yeap and then generate controller with rails generate helper from a bash. By default layout to your page will be application, but you can change it by explicit setting of layout('your_layout') in a controller

Comment: Ok will give that a try, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file config/routes.rb you define your routes. There is a special command 'root_to' to define your index route

```
root to: "homepage#index"
```

This tells rails to use the index method in the homepage_controller as the root of your application. It will look for a view called index.html.

The rails guides, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, give a pretty good explanation about routing.